# Developer Story Skill IQ Bug. Readding Improved Skill IQ will not add it to the profile header

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

There seems to be a bug with the 'Add Skill IQ' feature. I have previously added Pluralsight Skill IQ for JavaScript back in October 2020. I have retaken the assessment recently in November 2020. However, this time it allowed me to add the card itself, but the card doesn't get displayed in the top section of the profile anymore.

**Firstly**, the 'Technology Tags' box itself is now empty and has no tag in it:

[image]

**Secondly**, there was an error in the developer console as soon as I clicked the save button. Please find below a screenshot of the bug:

[image]

**Lastly**, the card itself gets added, but it doesn't show at the top of the profile any more:

**Card added:**

[image]

**But It doesn't show at the top, in the profile header:**

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed now.