# Can't add Pluralsight IQ to developer story header

Tags: bug, pluralsight-iq

I found a [similar bug reported almost a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402852/developer-story-skill-iq-bug-readding-improved-skill-iq-will-not-add-it-to-the) which apparently got fixed. So I'm going to report this one too hoping it would get fixed soon.

I took the *PHP Development Fundamentals* IQ test on Pluralsight, but it doesn't have a PHP tag and it also doesn't get added to my developer story header. I have no issues with other assessments such as JavaScript.

[image]

**PHP Missing from header!!!**

[image]

Comment: You can see the bug live on my developer story page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5173926

Comment: Related: As mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/862604) and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411253) by animuson, Jobs (and the associated Developer Story section) are being discontinued. No idea where that puts bug reports for either of those platforms in the meantime (an official announcement about this on this would be really nice).